# compress mark-up

Tags: html, xhtml, compression, markup, minify

*More a theoretical question.*

We compress/minify css & js, but has anyone ever thought or tried to compress mark-up?

**Q:** Benefits (Pro/Contra) of mark-up compression, possible tools and scripts.

As it's hard to have a *solution* for this Q, I'll take the most detailed answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

markup-compression is possible and widely used. there are a few possibilities (wich can be combined):

- [compression](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html) using deflate or gzip if the clients browser accepts this (wich all modern browsers should do)
- [minify markup](http://page-speed.net/tipps/minify-html.html) to kick out all the tabs, linebreaks and multiple spaces as they aren't displayed by the browser (note: this can lead to problems when using `<pre>` or `white-space: pre;`)
- leave out some markup (wich can be tricky and you really really shouldn't do this, but [google](http://www.google.com/) does. taking a look at the page-source you'll see theres no closing `body`-tag for example. for a site like google, this makes sense, as leaving out `</body>` saves 7 bytes of traffic, wich is really a lot if you think of the daily page-views of google)

Comment: (+1) Thanks for the links. I consider moving the "funny" part back into the Q, as the google tag handling falls into the category. About the minify link: Glad that I speak german :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't why you're looking for funny answers or think it's hard to have a solution to this question. Markup is routinely served in a compressed form, for example by using Apache's [mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html) module. Stack Overflow itself is serving you compressed markup.

Comment: I removed the "funny" part of the Q. That was indeed not necessary. I meant more in the fashion of "_creative_" approach.